# Linear Algebra - Question on definition

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear equation of the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is an equation that can be written in the form

$$a_1x_1+ \cdots + a_nx_n = b$$

Where $b$ and the coefficients $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are real or complex numbers. The subscript n may be any positive integer.

My question is, if the above is true, is it safe to say that:

"Any equation that can be rearranged algebraically as in the above equation is a linear equation, following the stated conditions for the constants and variables involved."

If you have any better version of such a type of definition, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply: a linear equation of the variables $\;x_1,...,x_n\;$ is an *homogeneous polynomial* of degree $\;1\;$ on those variables.

Comment: You can use LaTeX on this site. You don't need to use the Wikipedia mark-up. Have a look at the edit I made.

Comment: Timbuc: Sounds alot more simple for sure, but would it be perhaps too "academic" if teaching somebody new to the field about it for the first time?

Fly by Night: Thanks, will remember that, I'm new here :)

Comment: @TimoZaltair Point taken. Then I can't see any other option than describe it as it is: an polynomial in those n variables such that at each monomial appears exactly just one variable to the first power, and there is no free coefficient...I'd rather teach my students what a homogeneous polynomial in several variables is. :)

Comment: @Timbuc I actually see the point in that, the person might as well know it if they are going to study mathematics anyway. I'll try and make a simple description of what a homogeneous polynomial is then beforehand.
Thanks again.